# solid of revolution – exercise

Tags: integration, solid-of-revolution

Here is the exercise:

Find the volumes of the solids obtained if the plane regions R are rotated about
(a) the x-axis and
(b) the y-axis.

R is the finite region bounded by $y = x$ and $x = 4y – y^2$.

This is how I plot the situation:

[image: Picture of graphs]

I try to find the volume of the red graph from $x = 0$ to $x = 3$ rotated about the x-axis using the shell method.
This is because I'm planning on subtracting this area from the volume of the blue graph. However, I get a negative number, which is obviously wrong. Can somebody please tell me where I go wrong?

[image: My math reasoning (with the mistake)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set up the integral correctly. You are taking shell length as $(3 - (4y-y^2))$ but that is between vertical line $x = 3$ and the parabola. Also between $y = 1$ and $y = 3$, $(3 - (4y-y^2))$ is negative as the line $x = 3$ is to the left of the parabola. That is why your integral gives you negative value.

As you are finding volume of the shaded region (see below diagram) rotated around x-axis and using shell method, note that the shell length is $(4y - y^2 - y)$ as the region is bound on the left by the line $x = y$ and on the right by the parabola $x = 4y - y^2$.

[image]

So, $ ~ V =  \displaystyle \int_0^3 2 \pi y \cdot (3y - y^2) ~ dy = \frac{27 \pi}{2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @KishuInu also note that it is more straightforward to use disc method for rotation about y-axis. You can write here if you get stuck or need any clarification. I will reply in my morning.